# How to find sysctl.conf option name from /sys/devices path?

Tags: sysctl

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14429432/308237) that says I can enable/disable multicast snooping by writing to `/sys/devices/virtual/net/br-lan/bridge/multicast_snooping` "or in sysctl.conf".

I'd like to make it permanent but I can't work out what this value is called in `sysctl.conf`.

How do I figure out what `multicast_snooping` is called in `sysctl.conf` so that I can make the change persist over boot on this old OpenWRT device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no equivalent.

I suspect the mention of `sysctl` comes from a misconception and wasn’t actually tested. `multicast_snooping` is a device attribute exposed through [`sysfs`, typically mounted on `/sys`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sysfs.5.html), whereas `sysctl` accesses [`sysctl` variables exposed in `/proc/sys`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/index.html).

It is technically possible for the same setting to be exposed both through `sysfs` and `sysctl`, but that’s not the case here.